# The use of "Tuo" as a sign off in a letter

Tags: english-comparison, meaning

Is *"Tuo"* followed by the name meant as an intimate sign off or is it like the English term "yours" which can be used for anyone?

Comment: Yes, *Tuo* (or the feminine *Tua*) it is quite more intimate: I'd only use it when closing a letter to an actual friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Yours*** used in commercial letters corresponds to the following set formal phrases:

> - ***Sincerely yours***   (letter: used to sign off) (chiusura di lettere)    is:   ***Cordialmente, or Cordiali Saluti***
> - ***Yours faithfully***  formal,  (formula for ending correspondence) (chiusura di lettera)  is: ***In Fede or Distinti Saluti***.
> - ***Yours sincerely***   formal, (formula for ending correspondence) (chiusura di lettera) is :  ***Cordialmente, Cordiali Saluti***.

If you are referring to a private letter:

> - ***Yours***  adverb (formula used to end letter) (lettera: formula conclusiva)  is: ***tuo***  (adjective) usually followed by a noun or a name.

- The Italian  ***tuo*** has a more intimate nuance  with respect to the more general English usage of ***yours***.

Answer (score 4):

Signing off with "Tuo *nome*" is something I'd reserve for people you are actually close to: friends, girlfriend/boyfriend, wife/husband. Even to friends it feels too intimate, though something like

> Il tuo (aggettivi e.g. caro, lontano[per distanza], sempre) amico Jeff

is very friendly. OTOH,

> Il tuo Jeff

sounds excessive, IMHO. As an advice I would give, you should complement "Tuo" with the position you have towards that person, as shown in the first example.